# i18n for Feeds module

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am importing bulk data to my site using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. However, the module does not support i18n (languages) for taxonomies. I am thinking of updating the data directly at the database level, but then, what is the advantage of the module? Should I look for another module or combination of modules, instead? Thanks.

Comment: You can also use [feeds entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_et) which supports multiligual.